# Android. Getting link to the video stream from GoogleDrive

Tags: android, video-streaming, google-drive-api

I want to build my own android application that will show my videos on the device. I'd like to use Google Drive as a video storage for my application.

My question: Is there any way to get the link to the direct video stream for the video saved to my Google Drive? I'm considering two options here:

- the link is some constant so I'm able to store it in my database and give it to my android device to get the video from;
- the link is changing from time to time so having some video_id (I don't know if it exists), I can somehow get the link to the video stream and give it to my device.

I'll appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the files in Google Drive after authentication via the get, spend time on the API reference here | https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/#Files